# Back to top button slides up and down when scrolling even when condition is met

Tags: jquery

My back to top button seems to be in between deciding if to slide up or down when i scroll down a bit and when i stop scrolling it just slides up and down a couple of times then stays till i scroll again and repeats the same process.  Sometimes when i go all the way down on the page and go all the way up myself from scrolling the button slide up even thought the scrolltop property is 0. i am not sure if my code is the problem or the version of jquery im using
Using latest jquery version

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".totop").hide();

$(function(){
$(window).scroll(function(){
  if ($(this).scrollTop()>600)
  {
    $('.totop').slideDown();
  } 
  else
  {
    $('.totop').slideUp();
  }
});

$('.totop a').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('body,html').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 500);
});

});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same code on my page and it works well under jQuery version 1.6.4. I tested it on the latest jQuery version and actually it changed its behavior. It seems like now jQuery shows object before sliding it up. I made a little fix to you code and added throttle / debounce plug in to avoid calling scroll event multiple times. I think now it looks good.

Test http://jsfiddle.net/QXJ53/

```
/*
 * jQuery throttle / debounce - v1.1 - 3/7/2010
 * http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/
 * 
 * Copyright (c) 2010 "Cowboy" Ben Alman
 * Dual licensed under the MIT and GPL licenses.
 * http://benalman.com/about/license/
 */
(function(b,c){var $=b.jQuery||b.Cowboy||(b.Cowboy={}),a;$.throttle=a=function(e,f,j,i){var h,d=0;if(typeof f!=="boolean"){i=j;j=f;f=c}function g(){var o=this,m=+new Date()-d,n=arguments;function l(){d=+new Date();j.apply(o,n)}function k(){h=c}if(i&&!h){l()}h&&clearTimeout(h);if(i===c&&m>e){l()}else{if(f!==true){h=setTimeout(i?k:l,i===c?e-m:e)}}}if($.guid){g.guid=j.guid=j.guid||$.guid++}return g};$.debounce=function(d,e,f){return f===c?a(d,e,false):a(d,f,e!==false)}})(this);

$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".totop").hide();

    $(window).scroll($.throttle( 1000, function(){

      if ($(window).scrollTop()>100)
      {
        $('.totop').slideDown();
      } 
      else
      {
          if($('.totop').is(':visible')){

              $('.totop').slideUp();
          }

      }
    } ));

    $('.totop a').click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('body,html').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 500);
    });

});
```